# React native animation scrollview onScroll event not working with external method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, react-animated

I make a collapsing tollbar in ReactNative and i need stop de animation when the **Animated.ScrollView** contentOffset.y is equal 240. If i put any condition or call the Animated.event in external function it dosn´t work.

The **Animated.Value.stopAnimation()** doesn´t work either.

This works:

```
<Animated.ScrollView
   scrollEventThrottle={1}
   onScroll={
     Animated.event(
       [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollY}}}],
       {useNativeDriver: true}
     )
   }
>
...
```

This doesn´t work:

```
handlerScroll() {
  Animated.event(
    [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollY}}}]
    {useNativeDriver: true}
  )
}
...
render() {
 return(
   <Animated.ScrollView
      scrollEventThrottle={1}
      onScroll={this.handlerScroll.bind(this)}
    >
 )
}
...
```

and this doesn´t work either

```
<Animated.ScrollView
   scrollEventThrottle={1}
   onScroll={
     this.state.canScroll &&
     Animated.event(
       [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollY}}}],
       {useNativeDriver: true}
     )
   }
>
...
```

I don´t know what more i can use to stop my animation.

I need make this effect:

[image]

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No I didn't. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: @ToniChaz you need to return the result Animated.Event rather than just calling it, it's a function that returns an event handler.

Comment: @ToniChaz I know this is an old thread, but I'll reply regardless. Maybe someone else is looking for a solution. You need to pass the event object to the event function like so: `handlerScroll(event) {Animated.event(...)(event)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [stopping scroll event mapping](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#event), why not use `interpolate` for your animation with `extrapolate` set to 'clamp'? This will stop your animation from going beyond the bounds of input and output values.

Not sure what styles you’re trying to animate but for the sake of showing an example let’s say it was a translateY transform:

```
// onScroll map data to Animated value
onScroll={Animated.event(
    [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY } } }],
    { useNativeDriver: true }
)}

<Animated.View
    style={{
        transform: [{
            translateY: this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 240],
                outputRange: [0, -160],
                extrapolate: 'clamp' // clamp so translateY can’t go beyond -160
            })
        }]
    }}
>
    ...
</Animated.View>
```

Comment: Thank you @Zach-Gibson i will try it

Answer (score 4):

```
onScroll= {Animated.event(                                         
  [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this. state.scrollY } } }], 
  {                                                                
    useNativeDriver: true,                                         
    listener: event => {                                           
      handlerScroll(event);                             
    },                                                             
  },                                                               
)}
```

see https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#event