# How can I implement the UX of Twitter's Profile screen in react native，collapsible header (Sticky TabBar) with scrollable tabs?

Tags: react-native, sticky

i tried [react-navigation-collapsible](https://github.com/benevbright/react-navigation-collapsible) but it does not support tabs due to [react-native#21801](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21801)

similar question [Animating a single View based on multiple ScrollView(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980077/animating-a-single-view-based-on-multiple-scrollviews)

[React native animation scrollview onScroll event not working with external method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661557/react-native-animation-scrollview-onscroll-event-not-working-with-external-metho)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this one for having tabs in the header.

https://github.com/netguru/sticky-parallax-header

It can be implemented in this way.

https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/89a9dc

You can follow this one.

https://medium.com/@andi.gu.ca/a-collapsing-navbar-with-tabs-in-react-native-e80790588830